# CSS - IE don't get the margin-bottom from the last div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

I've a container, where i have some divs : header, content, footer (as a standart application).

this is the structure :

```
<body> 
    <div> 
        <div id="ROOT" > 
            <div id="ROOT_0" > 
                Header
            </div>

            <div id="ROOT_1" > 
                Content
            </div>

            <div id="ROOT_2" > 
                Footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The actual CSS :

```
html {height:101%;}
body {background:#999999;}

#ROOT{ background-color:#333333; width:980px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; overflow:auto;}
#ROOT_0{background-color:#FF9933; width:970px; text-align:center; float:left; margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px;}
#ROOT_1{width:980px; text-align:center; float:left; background-image:url(../img/sfondofc.jpg);}
#ROOT_2{background-color:#FF9933; width:970px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center; float:left; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px;}

background-color:#FF9933; width:970px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center; float:left; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px;
```

unfortunatly, on IE (6) i can't see the margin-bottom:5px; in the end, where i have the footer. Which propriety i need to change? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why did you set the height property of html to 101 percent ?

Comment: uhm, it's just a "trick". My website had some pages very long, other is not so long. So, if i always want the scrollbar at the left, i put html at 101%! so the website dont moves to the left-right :)